# SharePoint 2013 access denied error after changing Access mapping

Tags: url, web-application, alternate-access-mapping

After  changing URL access mapping Both on Central Adminand IIS for a web App, when I try to access to, I get the error Access Denied.   I've been doing this for a long time on Sp 2010 and it works. but not in SP 2013. 
is there reason ?

Comment: could you please give more information about the issue? what u changing? what authentication you are using? all sites in the web app getting access denied? do you have object cache?

Comment: Have a try clear the cookies and cache stored on your browser?

Comment: Yes, I've trued to clear the cache but the browser Login PopPup, asks for the credential all the time.  even if I try to Login with the Admin, the Windows Security Push me back.  If I try to set the Access mapping and IIS back, pointing to Hostname, it works!

Comment: Did my answer helps you to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Authentication Zones as per my understanding from your question. Please read the article given below & do needful for yourself.

[Configure Authentication Zones and Alternate Access Mappings](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2193844&seqNum=4)